# WinInet set session timeout

Tags: wininet

I am using WinInet  in C / C++ application to connect to a  ASP.NET Web Service.
I want to increase my SESSION TIMEOUT time.
Currently somehow SESSION Time out is 20 minutes and I want to increase it to 50 minutes.
Which option do it use for the option `INTERNET_OPTION_XXXXX` in

```
InternetSetOption(hInstance, INTERNET_OPTION_XXXXX,(LPVOID) &timeout, sizeof(timeout));
```

Comment: Solved: Session Timeout is set on IIS and is attribute of WebServive. Application can not control it.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike WinHTTP that has WinHttpSetTimeouts there is no equivalent function available at WinINet.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old question however it seems there is no info on how to do this on SO. So I am posting this in case someone wants to know how to set timeouts with WinINet.

Normally you would use `INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECT_TIMEOUT`,`INTERNET_OPTION_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT`, or `INTERNET_OPTION_SEND_TIMEOUT` with `InternetSetOption`. See here for details on the option flags: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/option-flags

However, there is a bug which it seems MS has not fixed in about 20 years. The above timeout flags simply don't work.

So the way to work around this is to **create second worker thread** to watch for the connection request. The second request will kill the main connection request if it doesn't receive response from server in the timeout set. See this MS KB article for details and example:
https://mskb.pkisolutions.com/kb/224318